# SQL-sum over dynamic period

Tags: sql, teradata

I have 2 tables: Customers and Actions, where each customer has uniqe ID (which can be found in each table).

Part of the customers became club members at a specific date (change between the customers). I'm trying to summarize their purchases until that date, and to get those who purchase more than (for example) 200 until they become club members.

For example, I can have the following customer:

```
custID  purchDate   purchAmount 
1       2015-05-12     100
1       2015-07-12     150
1       2015-12-29     320
```

Now, assume that custID=1 became a club member at 2015-12-25; in that case, I'd like to get `SUM(purchAmount)=250` (pay attention that I'd like to get this customer because 250>200).

I tried the following:

```
SELECT     cust.custID, SUM(purchAmount)totAmount 
FROM       customers cust
JOIN       actions   act
 ON        cust.custID=act.custID
WHERE      act.clubMember=1 
 AND       cust.purchDate<act.clubMemberDate
GROUP BY   cust.custID
HAVING     totAmount>200;
```

Is it the right way to "attack" this question, or should I use something like *while* loop over the clubMemberDate (which telling the truth-I don't know how to do)?

I'm working with Teradata.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't have a way to confirm your results then you're going to have a lot more problems than this. Your code should always be testable.

Comment: @TomH I didn't meant it that  way... I can test some customers, to see If I'm right... but I'm asking about the logic/syntax I choos, to make sure I'm not getting _"false positive"_ results

Comment: Your query matches your description, it's returning customer who purchased more than 200 before they became club member :)

Comment: As @dnoeth says, your query seems to match your description of the requirement. I'd still be concerned though if I wasn't certain of that just through my own testing.

Comment: you might also want to return act.clubMemberDate and max(cust.purchDate) in your `select` clause and confirm you don't want to include purchases on the day they became a club member.